# (int)object parsing gives an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception

Tags: c#

What does this exception can mean? In the "return" line I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

`name` and `pass` are properly filled, not null.

```
    public int GetUBID(string name, string pass)
    {
        var PassHash = GetPasswordHash(pass);

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
        {
            return (int)con.ExecuteScalar("spUser_getUBID",
                new { name = name, pass = PassHash },
                null, null,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); //<< Exception

        }
    }
```

Comment: Stored procedure returned null.

Comment: I executed the same procedure with same parameters in SQL server and it selected a cell, not null

Comment: Hm, it's really returns NULL in my programm. Investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **bet** if you check the value of `returnObject`, it will be `NULL`:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
{
     object returnedObject = con.ExecuteScalar("spUser_getUBID",
                                               new { name = name, pass = PassHash },
                                               null, null,
                                              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    // what value do you get here, in "returnedObject" ?? 
    if (returnedObject != null)
    {
        return (int)returnedObject;
    }
}
```

**ALWAYS** check your returned values for null - don't just **blindly assume** they're ok - many times they're **not** OK ! Just typecasting using `(int)` without a NULL check is bound to cause exceptions .....

Comment: Since it's not about a Dapper's, should I delete my question or should I edit it?